# Want to read/write file on network from my IIS but access denied

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, file-access, network-drive

I want to copy one file on the network drive ex. 192.168.0.32/ODfolder
I have hosted C# API on my IIS but when I call API they give me the error "Access Denied"

but when i debug on localhost it will run fine without error and copy the file on the network drive too.

Regards 
Rajat Khandelwal

Answer (score 1):

Check which user you are connecting using .Local IIS uses IIS_USERS. change the user or add permissions to user connecting to the file.

Comment: How to change the user ?

Comment: You can go to iis then select the application -right click- manage website-advanced settings-physical path credentials-select application user- add your account credentials.

Comment: The user name or password is incorrect. showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether that network drive is accessible from the machine where you have hosted your application, if yes then give write access on that folder to everyone or the user under which your application pool is running which is hosting your C# API.
Hope this helps. Happy coding...

Comment: I have already given all the permission. IIS user and the machine user too but not worked

Comment: open `IIS` select the `Application Pool` under which your application is running and select `Advanced Settings` from right panel and set the Identity to `Local System`

Comment: done the changes but not worked this too. error same access denied

Comment: if you are giving the path like this `192.168.0.32/ODfolder` in your code then change this to `\\192.168.0.32\ODfolder` and try...just a suggestion not sure how exactly you have given the path.

Comment: this path is correct "\\192.168.0.32\ODfolder"  i wrote the example only

Comment: when i create share drive on the same computer where iis is running it will work fine

Comment: This path is accessible from your IIS machine? when trying to open the path manually

Comment: yes, it is accessible. if we use the integrated security so maybe it will help.  i think we are missing any permission because when we debug the project it will work.

Comment: Yes you can try changing the Pipeline to Integrated from classic

Comment: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. this error is shows when i change to classic

Comment: I said to change to Integrated itself, anyways...check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611015/iis7-accessing-network-share might be useful

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the restart IIS button under application settings and it worked like magic!